Event handler in experience space tridion 10
We have event system to handle events like component save. It works fine in classic UI and able to debug it in VS but how to handle and debug for experience space and what is the going forward approach?
Thanks.

You might find that the w3wp.exe process does got get attached when trying to do debugging in experience space.  If that happens, ensure this is done.
When attaching the w3wp.exe process, you need to select code type as 'Managed (.Net framework 4.x) code (instead of Automatic).

The (TOM.NET) Event System is part of the CM Core implementation and TOM.NET events are triggered by actions performed on the (public) TOM.NET API. This includes:

Actions performed directly on TOM.NET API

by Templates
by Event Handlers
by Publisher Service


Actions performed through WCF Core Service. Including actions performed through:

Content Manager Explorer UI ("Classic UI")
Automated Workflow Activities (Workflow Agent)
Batch Processor Service
Search Indexer Service


Actions performed through Core Service REST. Including actions performed through:

Experience Space UI



Regarding how to debug your event handlers: you will have to attach to a CM Core host process, but there are multiple host processes:

w3wp (IIS Worker Process for Web Apps)

Core Service REST (used by Experience Space)
WCF Core Service HTTP-based endpoints
ECL Service HTTP-based endpoints


TcmServiceHost

WCF Core Service net.tcp-based endpoint (used by CME)
ECL Service net.tcp-based endpoints (used by CME)
TM Service net.tcp-based endpoints (used by CME)


TcmPublisher
TmService

UPDATE: Note that as of Sites 10.0, the TCM Website hosts both .NET Framework and .NET Core Web Apps:

.NET Framework: CME backend, Core Service REST, etc.
.NET Core: Experience Space BFF

There are separate debuggers for .NET Framework and .NET Core, so when attaching to the TCM Website w3wp.exe process, you have to ensure that you select the .NET Framework debugger (unless you want to debug Experience Space BFF, but there's not much to debug there; no backend extensions are loaded there). See also Brandon's answer.

Thanks. I am checking event handler only from experience space and trying to debug component save event which we already implemented. I can see expected message or error in the experience space but trying to understand how core service rest is calling the event handler code and attaching the process w3wp or TcmServiceHost is not working the way works in classic UI

Debugging event handlers should work just the same, only you will have to attach to w3wp instead of TcmServiceHost. Note that there may be multiple w3wp instances (for different App Pools), though. Please ensure you attach to the right one; check the title of the process in Visual Studio debugger.
